# Why does my pi keep telling me, port 443 network unreachable?

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh

I am trying to download a public key from  S3-amazonaws-com.  I don’t have a Wi-Fi that is working, so I am letting my raspberry pi use my iPhone is personal hotspot instead. 
I am using the

```
Wget
```

Command,  followed by the URL of that site.  I tried it once with out the s in HTTP, but it’s said that port 80 was unreachable.
 Before the error came up, the pi told me that it was able to resolve the IP address of the domain and subdomain that I provided.  I was also instructed to update the sources that list index in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

With a similar URL.  I’m using SFH to access the pi by the way

Comment: Make sure firewall on your Rpi and/or iPhone is not configured to block port 443.

Comment: If you refer to an error, then be so kind and post the complete error message. And a phone with hotspot IS a working WiFi network!

Comment: Well, for some reason, it turned out to be the iPhone after all. I found a Nother wireless network and I didn’t have the same problem I did before.  When I tried updating packages, I got an error something to the effect of updating from announce Akira posit Tori can be risky, or something like that. I’m using the MetroPCS personal hotspot on my phone, so not sure if that means anything.  Also, what does RPI mean?